# What is suvudu?

Tags: online-resources

I recently started looking at Suvudu's famous cage matches (e.g. [Quick Ben vs. Snape](http://sf-fantasy.suvudu.com/2011/03/cage-match-2011-quick-ben-versus-severus-snape.html)). The wiki page says that it's a site operated by Random House, but not much else. So is Suvudu a random collection of syllables, or is it something they picked up from one of their books? In the linked cage match, they also talk of Hell's Kitchen and Suvudu gods, how does that tie in?

Comment: " According to government records, the only names not yet trademarked are 'Popplers' and 'Zittzers'." "I know, we'll call them Popplers!"

Answer (score 3):

[Suvudu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suvudu) is simply an informal site operated by Random House, something like a blog, but I'd say it's a bit more than just that. It really looks to be somewhere between a blog and a fan site, run by the company.